# Modifying a config in Opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight, openflow, ietf-netconf, ietf-restconf, netconf

I am needing to modify my Openflow configurations in my Opendaylight (0.11.x sodium) system. I follow the [documentation](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/stable-sodium/users/operation.html) which has helped guide is in

- creating new configs
- deleting configs
- replacing configs
- **but I am not seeing an example or explanation on how to modify (or merge) a configuration.**

The top paragraph references modifying a config but doesn't actually show an example. And just to be clear, by *modification* I mean a *merge* operation. I.e., in terms of the [netconf edit-config RFC-6241](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241#section-7.2), I am wanting to modify only some of the leafs of a config, but keep older leafs.

Unfortunately, the options I see given in the openflow documentation is only creating, deleting, and replacing. We need to figure out how to do a merge.

In doing some research, it appears there is functionality with `REST PATCH` commands, however I am unable to get Opendaylight to work with it. Here is what I am trying:

```
PATCH //127.0.0.1:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:244354675513412/table/0/flow/105 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/yang.patch+xml
Accept: application/yang.patch+json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Postman-Token: 875a3c91-f6b1-4d21-8f2d-615b3c4b5cdd
Host: 127.0.0.1:8181
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1233
Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0dqx2exo4lrydz1adjhvc9lum374.node0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<flow xmlns='urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory' xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <strict>false</strict>
    <id>105</id>
    <priority>9</priority>
    <table_id>0</table_id>
    <hard-timeout>0</hard-timeout>
    <idle-timeout>0</idle-timeout>
    <flow-name>10dot0SubnetToPort1_from_4</flow-name>
    <match>
       <ethernet-match>
           <ethernet-type>
               <type>2048</type>
           </ethernet-type>
           <ethernet-destination>
               <address>FF:FF:29:01:19:61</address>
           </ethernet-destination>
           <ethernet-source>
               <address>00:00:00:11:23:AE</address>
           </ethernet-source>
       </ethernet-match>
    </match>
    <instructions>
        <instruction>
            <order>1</order>
            <apply-actions>
                <action>
                    <order>0</order>
                    <output-action>
                        <output-node-connector>6</output-node-connector>
                        <max-length>66</max-length>
                    </output-action>
                </action>
            </apply-actions>
        </instruction>
    </instructions>
</flow>
```

But the response I get back is: `406 Not Acceptable` and nothing else... No `<error...` rpc-response or anything. I also am studying the log files in DEBUG and TRACE mode and can't pick up any hint as to what is going wrong.

I also tried pasting in `nc:operation='merge'` to each element like this...

```
...
<output-action nc:operation='merge'>
   <output-node-connector nc:operation='merge'>6</output-node-connector>
   <max-length nc:operation='merge'>66</max-length>
</output-action>
...
```

But this also results in the same `406 Not Acceptable` response.

**Goal: how does one properly merge/modify a config in OpenDaylight/Openflow**

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about 'target' field and its function. However, target field should only contain the name of resource/prefix you're trying to modify.

I'd suggest you to change your flow and target resources accordingly. What I mean by that is you need to make sure the flow and target resources are leading to same resource you're trying to configure.

It should be something like :

PATCH localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A{{OFID}}/table=0/flow=259/instructions/instruction=0/flow-node-inventory:apply-actions/order=4

and keep Target resource as = /flow-node-inventory:action[flow-node-inventory:order='4']

Try GET on the flow to confirm you're receiving only the resource you're trying to modify/delete.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install 'odl-restconf-nb-RFC8040' endpoint on your karaf shell. ODL provides two end-point for restconf communication. Although less documents on RFC-8040, yang-patch gives no error through that. (YANG-PATCH allows "create, delete, insert, merge, move, replace, remove" operations. Creating, modifying and deleting configs can be done by changing operation in this payload. https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netconf/en/latest/user-guide.html#reconfiguring-an-existing-connector )

RFC-8040 defines YANG-PATCH according to this RFC : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-yang-patch-14#section-2

Your header looks good.

Your API will begin like : PATCH //127.0.0.1:8181/rests/data/.../...

Comment: thank you for this hint. My co-worker and I have been messing around with this plugin and we can do very broad actions, such as delete an entire flow, but we can't produce precise patches what changes various aspects of a flow. Are there examples out there of using PATCH against flows?

Comment: Glad I could be of help. 
Further more information on OpenDaylight configuration is on their Magnesium(and onwards versions)
https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netconf/en/latest/user-guide.html#reconfiguring-an-existing-connector
(operation "merge" should work as PATCH for client)
Also to add, Yang-PATCH introduced in RFC 8072(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8072) could be of help in finding correct payload. 
Make sure to use RFC-8040 format of API.

Thank you for my first reputation :)

Comment: check out William's question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377498/1582712) we work together and he has been doing a deep dive into the PATCH method and hitting a wall. I wonder if you can help?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to execute yang-patch using the RFC 8040 endpoint and I'm still having some issues--it appears I cannot delete a target with a value other than `"/"`. This is to modify flows in the openflow plugin.

Querying a particular flow here is what I get:

```
GET localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A{{OFID}}/table=0/flow=259/instructions/instruction=0
```

Response:

```
{
    "flow-node-inventory:instruction": [
        {
            "order": 0,
            "apply-actions": {
                "action": [
                    {
                        "order": 4,
                        "output-action": {
                            "output-node-connector": "2",
                            "max-length": 60
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "order": 0,
                        "set-field": {
                            "ipv4-source": "10.0.0.254/32"
                        },
                        "set-nw-src-action": {
                            "ipv4-address": "10.0.0.254/32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "order": 1,
                        "set-field": {
                            "ipv4-destination": "10.0.0.21/32"
                        },
                        "set-nw-dst-action": {
                            "ipv4-address": "10.0.0.21/32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "order": 2,
                        "output-action": {
                            "output-node-connector": "2",
                            "max-length": 60
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "order": 3,
                        "set-field": {
                            "ipv4-destination": "10.0.0.29/32"
                        },
                        "set-nw-dst-action": {
                            "ipv4-address": "10.0.0.29/32"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is expected--I've installed a flow with specific actions and they're listed appropriately.

Now, let's say I want to delete the action with `order=4` above.  I would think I would create my request in the following way:

```
PATCH localhost:8181/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow%3A{{OFID}}/table=0/flow=259/instructions/instruction=0
```

Content-type and accept-types are set according to the yang.patch requirements.

Body:

```
{
  "ietf-restconf:yang-patch" : {
    "patch-id" : "0",
    "edit" : [
        {
        "edit-id" : "edit1",
        "operation" : "delete",
        "target" : "/flow-node-inventory:apply-actions/flow-node-inventory:action[flow-node-inventory:order='4']"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "ietf-yang-patch:yang-patch-status": {
        "patch-id": "0",
        "edit-status": {
            "edit": [
                {
                    "edit-id": "edit1",
                    "errors": {
                        "error": [
                            {
                                "error-type": "protocol",
                                "error-tag": "data-missing",
                                "error-path": "/(urn:opendaylight:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)nodes/node/node[{(urn:opendaylight:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)id=openflow:152169965450049}]/AugmentationIdentifier{childNames=[(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)description, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)supported-actions, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)hardware, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)switch-features, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)stale-meter, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)supported-instructions, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)meter, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)serial-number, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)stale-group, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)supported-match-types, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)port-number, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)group, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)manufacturer, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table-features, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)software, (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)ip-address]}/(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table/table[{(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)id=0}]/flow/flow[{(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)id=259}]/instructions/instruction/instruction[{(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)order=0}]/instruction/apply-actions/action/action[{(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)order=4}]",
                                "error-message": "Data does not exist"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know the data exists, but it seems that I cannot request a delete for the particular element I've specified in the target.  Indeed, the only way I can delete a particular element is to use `"target" : "/"`, which will delete the child elements according to the last hierarchical element in the URL.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here--I would have thought I could specify a target and get a delete to execute accordingly, but I'm not sure what else I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue of global-level config/node-level config in netconf edit operation. ODL sends out netconf RPCs to mounted netconf devices. I'm certain of later version (11.2 and on) are supporting yang-patch at node-level config. Not sure which version you're using ??

Also this could be an issue of netconf device you're trying to configure, if node-level config is not supported and enabled, ODL could receive error from netconf response.

Either way, checking yang-tool logs on ODL can make this clear for you. you can enable logs on karaf for yang-tools and can set-up detailed logs. That could explain this more.